# How to compare a list containing another list in junit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit5, hamcrest

I have three classes as follows :

```
public class Foo {
 private Long fooId;
 private String fooName;
 private List<Bar> bars;
}

public class Bar  {
    private Long barId;
    private String barName;
    private Foo foo;
}

public class FooBar {
    List<Foo> foo;
    List<Bar> bars;
}
```

`FooBar` is what I am getting in the response. I am little bit confused about how to compare, especially `Foo` using `hasItem()` of `hamcrest.Matchers.*` or is there any better way. how we can compare this in Junit5?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `Foo` and `Bar` should have something in common, a basis for comparison, by which it will be possible to compare them.

If they do not have anything in common, I do not see any way to compare *incomparable* objects.

As long as your `Foo` and `Bar` have something in common, or at least they override`.equals()` and implement their own ones which would enable comparison of these two (can mutually compare these two types), you can use:

```
assertIterableEquals(expected, actual); //from org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
```

This method asserts whether two iterables are deeply equal.

Note, that if both *expected* and *actual* are nulls, they are considered equal.

Comment: The only time `foo` will be equal to `bars` is going to be true is if they are both `null`.  Since `foo` is a collection of `Foo`, `bars` is a collection of `Bar`, and both extend `Object`, there is no other way for those collections to be equal.  There is no reason to use `assertIterableEquals` if the only goal is to identify if they are both `null`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown do you mean that they should implement `.equals()` from some common supertype?

Comment: "do you mean that they should implement .equals() from some common supertype?" - No.  I meant there is no good reason to use `assertIterableEquals` in a case like this.

Comment: But why? List implements Collection, and Collection has equals. I don't understand why this is not going to work.

Comment: The only iterables in the question are `List<Foo>` and `List<Bar>`.  Since `Foo` and `Bar` don't share any inheritance potential except for `Object`, there is no way for a `List<Foo>` to be equal to a `List<Bar>` unless they are both `null`.

Comment: They would only be equal if they are `null`, or if they are both empty.

Comment: "Since Foo and Bar don't share any inheritance potential except for Object" - and that's what I said above. If `Foo` and `Bar` would implement some mutually working equals, then this is going to work. If they don't, there is no way to compare them in any other way (unless implementing this manually in some other way).

Comment: What do you think is a better way for asserting this equality?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown could you please comment on whether you still think that my edited answer is not correct?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown crude example of what Giorgi is getting at: https://ideone.com/MIKqUq

Comment: @Michael but with actual implementation, instead of `return true;` :) actually, I don't see any other way, how can I compare *Apple* to *Orange*, if they have nothing in common.

Comment: Having an `equals` method that is hardcoded to return `true` is a really bad idea and is going to break a bunch of things, including standard collection behavior.  "how can I compare Apple to Orange, if they have nothing in common - Why do you want to compare to things that have nothing in common?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I'm sorry, but I have a feeling that you're not reading what I write. 1. **Yes**, of course, `return true;` was (I assume) a skeleton example, and as I said, it rather should be implemented; 2. That's what OP asks for, if `Foo` and `Bar` are totally different types, if they have something in common, then I still don't understand why my answer wouldn't be reasonable. I just tried to provide what, as a maximum, I could think of in this quite uncertain example.